# UK spouse visa -English language requirements

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, resident-permit

Hi I am currently on student visa in UK, and in my final year of PhD in UK. The IELTS (academic-has expired two years ago). What are my choices of fulfilling english requirements for Spouse visa?

Answer (score 4):

The [immigration rules Appendix KoLL](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-koll) says that having an academic degree taught in English is sufficient, with the degree itself being the documentary evidence:

> 2.2 For the purposes of paragraph 2.1, an applicant demonstrates sufficient knowledge of the English language if:
>
> ...
>
> iii) the applicant has obtained an academic qualification(not a professional or vocational qualification), which is deemed by UK NARIC to meet the recognised standard of a Bachelor’s or Master’s degree or PhD in the UK, from an educational establishment in one of the following countries: Antigua and Barbuda; Australia; The Bahamas; Barbados; Belize; Dominica; Grenada; Guyana; Ireland; Jamaica; New Zealand; St Kitts and Nevis; St Lucia; St Vincent and The Grenadines; Trinidad and Tobago; the UK; the USA; and provides the specified documents;

Comment: Hi, But I have not completed my Degree yet, It will be completed next year and I need to apply now. So will it still be acceptable if I show some documentry evidence thaht the degree is being reserached in English?